# Auto Backup MySQL database with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, database-backups

I have created a backup option on Codeigniter project. Now I want to the backup database automatically each day with a fixed time.

Here is my backup code:

```
function dbbackup(){
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $prefs = array(     
        'format'      => 'zip',             
        'filename'    => 'my_db_backup.sql'
        );

    $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs); 
    $db_name = "backup_on_" . date("d_m_Y_h_i_s_a") . ".zip";
    $save = 'uploads/dbbackup/'.$db_file_name;
    $this->load->helper('file');
    write_file($save, $backup); 
    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download($db_name, $backup);
}
```

Is there any specific query to backup automatically?

Comment: saving backup files in uploads directory is foolishness, if its accessible by public

Comment: but why brother @AkshayHegde

Comment: is it ok if someone steal your website data ?, thats the reason

Comment: It's not accessible by the public so don't worry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use `crontab` and `mysqldump` to take backup at desired time, there is actually no need to use `dbutil` class, `mysqldump` will be faster and reliable compare to `dbutil` class.

If you read source code of [`mysqli_utility`, `_backup` method](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_utility.php#L80), you will understand how it affects performance.

Say example to take backup everyday at `14:30`

```
crontab -e
```

Make a entry like below

```
30 14 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump --user=USER --password=PASSWORD --databases DBNAME1 DBNAME2 | gzip > /home/someuser/backup.$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S").sql.gz
```

Save crontab

Comment: So I just add the below code on my bottom of the code, right?

Comment: @Sabbir, you've mistaken, this is not php code, you have to set it in your crontab, if you're unaware here is [tutorial for you](https://www.howtogeek.com/101288/how-to-schedule-tasks-on-linux-an-introduction-to-crontab-files/)

Comment: @Sabbir  on your terminal, execute this command `/usr/bin/mysqldump --user=USER --password=PASSWORD --databases DBNAME1 DBNAME2 | gzip > /home/someuser/backup.$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S").sql.gz` and verify, but don't forget to replace username, password, database name and backup location

Comment: But Will I do it to Live Server? I need this for live server

Comment: @Sabbir, yes you can, no issue it will just export databases, mysql takes care of locking tables while exporting, if you're not confident, test it on some other machine with small database, and then verify, `mysqldump` is standard tool.

Comment: Can i use like this in code

`passthru("30 14 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpwd --databases $dbname > $save | gzip > /home/someuser/backup.$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S").sql.gz");`

Comment: @Sabbir `30 14 * * *` is for scheduling in crontab

Answer (score 0):

If you have it on a live server, you could setup a cron jobs to call the php file. If you want to set it up locally then you could use something like task scheduler of the corresponding operating system to call the php script followed by the url as the argument. Or you could make a `bat` file and add it on a scheduler, contains something like :

```
php 'path/to/project/index.php' dbbackup
```

If you are using live server, you could open up the cron table by using this command on the terminal :

```
crontab -e
```

Then add an entry to make a schedule to suits your needs,
each line of the crontab file takes six arguments, which are, in order:

- minutes (0 to 59)
- hours (0 to 23)
- day of month (1 to 31)
- month (1 to 12)
- day of week (0 – 6)
- command (command to be executed)

Example :

```
0 13 * * * php [application_path]/index.php dbbackup
```

Comment: I use live server